# Codeigniter can't unserialize - Error destroys session on setting flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with the CodeIgniter 2.1.3 Session Class.

So I noticed this on setting some flashdata. on other modules I haven't this error. It seems to be specific to that one module.

It happens when I run the `form_validation` and i set the flashdata -> in that moment the framwork wants to want to unserialize and got an error - that destroys my session.

Error Log:

```
Severity: Notice  --> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 256 bytes /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ges/system/libraries/Session.php 727
```

I tried all new Session classes of CI, also tried to trim before unserialize. But it still kills my session.

Here is the part code of my controller (i had to change some var names cause security):

```
<?php

public function add($reg = false)
{

        if (!$reg)
                redirect('tickets');

        restrict_access(array(1,4), '/');
        $url = url_ci_decrypt($reg);
        parse_str($url, $url_data);

        $data                = $this->session_user->getSessionUserData();
        $data['title']       = 'XXXXX';
        $data['reg']         = $url_data;
        $data['reg']['name'] = $this->tickets_model->getTicketTypeText($url_data['type']);
        $data['reasons']     = $this->tickets_model->getTicketReasons();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|min_length[20]|max_length[2000]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->input->post()) {
                $posted  = $this->input->post();
                $newdata = array(
                        'x1' => $this->session->userdata['x1'],
                        'x2' => $this->session->userdata['x2'],
                        'x3' => $url_data['x3'],
                        'x4' => $url_data['x4'],
                        'x5' => 0,
                        'x6' => $posted['text']
                        );
                $result = $this->tickets_model->addTicket($newdata);
                if ($result === true) {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'message1');
                } else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'message2');
                }
                redirect('/');
        } else if ($this->input->post()) {
                $posted       = $this->input->post();
                $data['text'] = strip_tags($posted['message']);
        }

        /* loading views */
}

// some more modules...
```

Here is also my config part for sessions:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'user_session';
$config['sess_expiration']       = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = true;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = true;
$config['sess_use_database']    = true;
$config['sess_table_name']       = 'user_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']         = false;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = true;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: How much data are you storing? Cookies have a 4Kb limit IIRC. If the serialized string gets truncated you can't unserialize it correctly

Comment: it's less than 4Kb. i'm using UTF-8 and the string lenght is about 500-600 chars.

But if `sess_encrypt_cookie` is `false` it works fine! - but this would be a big security problem...

Answer (score 3):

It's works after I change "Collation" in PHPMyAdmin on all columns in "ci_session" table from "latin1_swedish_ci" to "latin2_general_ci".

I'm from Poland, so in my national language I have letters like "ł", "ś" etc. When I add some flashdata with this letters, its been replaced for "?" and after unserialize I have a bug.

Please check it in your project.